# Arguments in newcommand

Tags: macros

I am currently using MathJax inside of a Jupyter notebook running a Julia 1.0 kernel and attempting to use `\newcommand`, but it seems like the documentation and posts I've read for `\newcommand` conflicts with what I am seeing.

When I use: `\newcommand{\Dot}[2][X]{\mathbf{#2}\cdot\mathbf{#1}}`, my expectation is that when I use `\Dot{a}{b}` I would see the output of `\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}`, however I am seeing output of `\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{X}b`. In order to see my expected output, I have to use: `\newcommand{\Dot}[3][X]{\mathbf{#3}\cdot\mathbf{#2}}`. I thought that maybe the first argument was some sort of function name placeholder or something a la the first element of `argv` in C, so I tried `\newcommand{\Dot}[2][X]{\mathbf{#3}\cdot\mathbf{#2}}`, but then use of the macro doesn't render.

What am I missing here?

Comment: With `\newcommand{\Dot}[2][X]{\mathbf{#2}\cdot\mathbf{#1}}` you have to use it like `\Dot[b]{a}`.  The optional argument always has to be the first and given in square brackets, see also https://latexref.xyz/_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand.html#g_t_005cnewcommand-_0026-_005crenewcommand

Comment: Also keep in mind that **MathJax is not LaTeX**.

Comment: Note that questions about MathJax are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was about MathJax not about LaTeX

Comment: You need to ask the mathjax people how they support newcommand with optional args. As mentioned this is javascript not latex, so off topic

Comment: @MadyYuvi I don't see why this is off topic, the OP mentioned mathjax but the syntax error causing the problem applies to latex and has a purely latex answer as given in Henri's first comment above.

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcommand{\Dot}[2][X]{\mathbf{#2}\cdot\mathbf{#1}}
```

defines a command with an *optional* argument, and optional arguments are always marked with `[]` in LaTeX and placed as the *first* argument (if used), so the use would be

`\Dot{a}` to produce a·X

`\Dot[Y]{a}` to produce a·Y

The declaration that would match the call that you tried would be to have two mandatory arguments so

```
\newcommand{\Dot}[2]{\mathbf{#2}\cdot\mathbf{#1}}
```

with use

`\Dot{X}{a}` to produce a·X

`\Dot{Y}{a}` to produce a·Y